# Checking if the excel is blank or not

Tags: excel

I am trying to send a system-generated email. which contains an excel. But I want to know if the excel is blank or not. how can I check that? And how to check a specified range is blank or not?

Comment: How do you want to do that? using any programming language? Is excel also being generated using some program?

Comment: Yes..using golang.

Answer (score 1):

The below code loop all worksheets and check if are empty:

```
Sub Empty_Area()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        With ws
        
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.UsedRange) = 0 And .Shapes.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Empty"
            Else
                MsgBox "Not empty"
            End If
            
        End With
        
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

The below code check if sheet1 range A1:A10 is empty:

```
Sub Empty_Area()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    
                            
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Empty"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not empty"
    End If
                            
End Sub
```